# Custom filtering on default Experience Analytics Dashboard reports

Tags: sitecore

So I am looking into extending a little bit the Sitecore reporting in the Experience Analytics Dashboard by adding an additional (custom) filter.

So the filters are:

1. Date Range Filter (pre-existing)
2. Subsite Filter (pre-existing)
3. Store Filter (NEW)

Please notice that I am not doing a static report - I would like EXISTING reports to take into consideration my NEW custom filter.

I have used the ideas introduced in the [post by Mohammed Syam](https://sitecoreinfo.blogspot.com/2017/04/building-custom-analytics-report-part5.html) in order to provide the frontend part of the new filter (and it is there, with combobox coming up, URL adding an additional query string parameter). I am just not sure where would I go to tweak the "receiving end" for existing reports.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend to review the standard Sitecore documentation too, see [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/81/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-a-custom-report-filter-and-segment.html) about how to create a custom report filter.

Comment: Thank you @KateOrlova! I saw this one. It is filtering data from what is available, not a new filter in the interface (what I was particularly looking for). My need is to have it dynamically available for selection. The filtering you are talking about is rather "hardcoded" if it makes sense.

Comment: @KateOrlova - in the end I had a great idea from my co-worker Roland Villemoes, and I have implemented what I wanted by injecting my Stores under Sites filter. "CustomValues" attributes being added to each analytics push and then Sitecore "tricked" to think each of the stores is a "site". 

Please see here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56137233/sitenames-table-in-experiece-analytics-reporting-db-how-when-it-is-being-pop

Comment: Ok, great, @Sasha, I am glad that you found a good solution.