# SiteNames table in Experiece Analytics Reporting DB - how / when it is being populated?

Tags: sitecore8

I am working on some custom reporting and would like to know how and when the "SiteNames" table is being populated in Experience Analytics Reporting DB. Is it a processor? Which one? Something else?

I am on Sitecore 8.2
And here is the table screenshot to give an idea what I am talking about. The same table is used, by the way, to populate "Sites" filter on the Experience Analytics Dashboard.

[image]

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

All right... I have the spot... things were not populating in SiteNames table because of some errors I had, so it never reached the place to do the updates to the table. Funny, hah?

So if you ever want to have data reported in Reporting DB under not the actual sites but eCommerce Store for example, you need to add a custom processor to update the "args.Context.Visit.SiteName" property and this is how it will go into reporting.

When is it useful? When you would like to have custom reports but slice the analytics data in the "Sites" filer by something else (eCommerce Store in my example) and this will be now present in the dropdown in Experience Analytics Dashboard (for all reports).

P.S. If curious, this is where the SiteName update is:

[image]